# Rewrite tactic fails to find term occurrence within pattern matching

Tags: coq

In Coq, I'm having problems with applying the `rewrite` tactic in the following situation:

```
Section Test.

Hypothesis s t        : nat -> nat.
Hypothesis s_ext_eq_t : forall (x : nat), s x = t x.

Definition dummy_s : nat -> nat :=
  fun n => match n with
         | O => 42
         | S np => s np
       end.

Definition dummy_t : nat -> nat :=
  fun n => match n with
         | O => 42
         | S np => t np
       end.

Goal forall (n : nat), dummy_s n = dummy_t n.
Proof.
  intro n. unfold dummy_s. unfold dummy_t.
```

At that stage, the local context and current goal look as follows:

```
1 subgoals, subgoal 1 (ID 6)

s : nat -> nat
t : nat -> nat
s_ext_eq_t : forall x : nat, s x = t x
n : nat
============================
match n with
| 0 => 42
| S np => s np
end = match n with
      | 0 => 42
      | S np => t np
      end
```

Now it should be possible to apply the `rewrite` tactic to replace the occurence of `s np` in the goal by `t np`, thereby making it possible to solve the goal using `reflexivity`. However,

```
rewrite s_ext_eq_t.
```

gives

```
Toplevel input, characters 0-18:
Error: Found no subterm matching "s ?190" in the current goal.
```

What am I doing wrong? One *can* get into a situation where `rewrite` is applicable via

```
 destruct n. 
   (* n = 0 *)
   reflexivity.
   (* n > 0 *)
   rewrite s_ext_eq_t.
   reflexivity.
 Qed.
```

but in the actual situation I am facing, several such destructs would be necessary, and I wonder whether `rewrite` or a variant of it is able to do this automatically.

---

*Addendum* The above situation naturally occurs when proving that a function defined via well-founded recursion has the desired fixed point property:

Suppose `A: Type` and that `R: A -> A -> Prop` is a well-founded relation, i.e. we have `Rwf: well_founded R`. Then, given a type family `P: A -> Type` we may construct a section

```
Fix : forall (x : A), P a
```

through recursion over `R`, with the recursion step given as a function

```
 F : forall x:A, (forall y:A, R y x -> P y) -> P x
```

See https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Wf.html However, to show that `Fix` indeed has the fixed point property

```
  forall (x : A), Fix x = F (fun (y:A) _ => Fix y)`
```

we need to provide a witness

```
  F_ext : forall (x:A) (f g:forall y:A, R y x -> P y),
             (forall (y:A) (p:R y x), f y p = g y p) -> F f = F g.
```

i.e. we have to show that `F` does not use anything else from the given `f: forall y:A, R y x -> P y` but its values. Of course, in any concrete situation, this should be trivial to verify, but when one tries to prove it, one runs into a situation a minimal example of which I have presented above: One is facing a huge equality of two copies of the code for the recursion step, one time with `f` and another time with `g`. Your assumption tells  that `f` and `g` are extensionally equal, so one should be able to rewrite them. However, in the code for the recursion step, there might be a large number of pattern matchings and new variables that doesn't make sense in the local context, hence it would be (unnecessarily?) quite tedious to `destruct` dozens of times before being allowed to apply `rewrite`.

Comment: I think `s np` is not a subterm, because np is a pattern variable, so `rewrite` doesn't work on it. Using  `destruct` creates concrete subterms for which rewrite works, so I would use that if possible: `destruct n; auto.`   Or, if you assume `functional extensionality`, then you can do `Require Import FunctionalExtensionality. replace s with t; auto using functional_extensionality.` but you might not want to introduce an extra axiom just for that.  So there are probably better ways to do this...

Comment: @larsr: Thank you for your comment. I'm still wondering, however, whether a tactic has been or could be implemented that automates this destruction process, thereby allowing to use `rewrite` on any sub*expression* of the goal, even if its not well-typed in the current local context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment above, it is *not* possible to perform the rewrite directly on the branch of the `match` statement, because `np` is not in scope in the top-level environment. As far as Coq's theory is concerned, a proof of your statement *will* have to destruct `n` at some point.

Although I am not aware of any tactics for automating this kind of problem, it is not too hard to come up with some custom ltac code for solving your problem without too much pain:

```
Ltac solve_eq :=
  try reflexivity;
  match goal with
  | |- match ?x with _ => _ end
       = match ?x with _ => _ end =>
    destruct x; auto
  end.

Goal forall (n : nat), dummy_s n = dummy_t n.
Proof.
  intro n. unfold dummy_s. unfold dummy_t.
  solve_eq.
Qed.
```

If your extensional equality results are hypotheses that appear in your context, then `solve_eq` should be able to solve many goals of this shape; if not, you might have to add extra lemmas to your hint database.

Comment: Thank you - and sorry for my very late answer!