# Rewrite with variable from inner scope?

Tags: coq

Is it possible to rewrite something that uses variables from another scope,
such as a function call that uses a variable from a `match`, `fun`, or `fix` ?
For example,

```
Theorem foo (f : nat -> nat) (rw : forall x, f x = 5) x : match x with
| 0 => 5
| S a => f a
end = 5.
  rewrite rw.
(* Error: Found no subterm matching "f ?M160" in the current goal. *)

  destruct x; try rewrite rw; apply eq_refl.
Qed.
```

So, the theorem is provable, but trying to rewrite rw initially fails,
seemingly because `a` is in another scope.  But, the rewrite applies
unconditionally, so it seems like it should apply there too.

Of course, this is a toy example.  Assume that, in a real-world scenario,
getting into the scope is a bit more complicated than just a destruct.

From [Rewrite tactic fails to find term occurrence within pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721397/) it looks like this isn't possible in Coq.  So, is it just that it isn't implemented, or does it cause contradictions or allow for bad behavior like smuggling variables out of their scope?
What about harder cases like `fix` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have likely heard that the Logic of Coq is not powerful enough to derive functional exensionality.

Now what you prove above is a point wise equality, that is you prove that an applied function has a certain value.

A rewrite in the match would correspond to a proof that two unapplied functions are equal: The original match statement (which is a function of x) and the rewritten match statement (also a function of x). This means you would prove a more general result as intermediate step - and Coq's logic is not able to prove this more general result.

Functional extensionality is compatible with Coq's logic, though. So one can add it as axiom and then one can add some setoid instances which allow to setoid_rewrite under binders. But afaik this does not work for rewrites under matches either.

It would also be possible to detect that in the end you prove a point wise equality, do the destruct behind the scenes, do the point wise rewrite and put things together again, but this would work only in rather trivial cases, which I guess are not sufficiently interesting to implement this.

To close here is an example of proving functional extensionality (suggested by the edit by @scubed) with a rewrite under binders - which is enabled by a global type class instance which is itself based on the functional extensionality axiom. So this proves an axiom with itself and it doesn't help for your match case, but it shows that rewriting under binders is equivalent to functional extensionality.

```
Require Import PeanoNat.
Require Import Setoid.
Require Import Morphisms.

Definition fun1 (x : nat) := x + 1.
Definition fun2 (x : nat) := 1 + x.

Example Fun1EqFun2: fun1 = fun2.
Proof.
  unfold fun1, fun2.
  Fail setoid_rewrite Nat.add_comm.
Abort.

Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.

(* This is derived from the error message of setoid_rewrite above *)
Global Instance:
forall (A B : Type),
Proper
        (@pointwise_relation A B eq ==>
         @pointwise_relation A B eq ==> Basics.flip Basics.impl) eq.
Proof.
  (* See what all this Setoid stuff actually means ... *)
  unfold Proper, pointwise_relation, respectful, Basics.flip, Basics.impl.
  intros A B f g fgeq f' g' fg'eq gg'eq.
  apply functional_extensionality.
  intros x.
  rewrite fgeq, fg'eq, gg'eq.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Theorem eq_arg (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) : f = (fun x => f x). reflexivity. Qed.

Lemma functional_extensionality' :
  forall (A B : Type), forall (f g : A -> B),
  (forall a : A, (f a) = (g a)) -> f = g.
Proof.
  intros.
  setoid_rewrite eq_arg at 2.
  setoid_rewrite H.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you!  Ah, so it comes out to function extensionality.  That makes it much more clear.

In looking, I also found
```
Theorem eq_arg (f : nat -> nat) : f = (fun x => f x).
  apply eq_refl.
Qed.
```
So, if I could rewrite here, it would be extensionality, in that there isn't actually an argument in this case, which demonstrates what you are saying.

Comment: @scubed: thaks for the edit suggest! I extended it to a proof of functional extensionality based on a rewrite under binders - which should make it absolutely clear.